Behavior of argmax of dependent random variables
Suppose $X_1...X_N$ are a set of dependent random variables with the same support (continuous). They do not necessarily have the same distribution. Let $Y$ be $\text{argmax} ({X_1... X_n})$, so with support $\{1 ... N\}$. What can we say about the discrete Shannon entropy of $Y$ if we know the differential entropies of $X_1...X_n$? Intuitively, I would expect that larger entropies in the individual RVs leads to greater spread of the argmax, so $H(Y)$ would be higher. I am having trouble formalizing this intuition, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Not really: you could have two iid low-entropy random variables, where the entropy of $Y$ is high, or two random variables with very high entropy, but one of which is always $< 0,$ and the other $> 0$. You can even engineer families where increasing the differential entropy of $(X_1, X_2)$ decreases the entropy of $Y$ (e.g., $X_1 \sim \mathrm{Unif}(-M, 1), X_2 \sim \mathrm{Unif}(-1,M)$ with $M > 1$.


Intuitively, I would expect that larger entropies in the individual RVs leads to greater spread of the argmax

I wouldn't. Take the case of iid random variables, then $H(Y)= \log n$ , i.e., the maximum, irrespective of the individual densities/entropies.
